# Unable to retrieve information through facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication

I am trying to retrieve information through Facebook graph api, using the below code which is returning me nothing, I wrote this code after getting help from on line documentations etc. but it's not working.

Kindly help me with this.

```
include ('src/facebook.php');    
$app_id = "160336957418730";
$app_secret = "************************";
        $facebook = new Facebook( array('appId' => $app_id, 'secret' => $app_secret, ));

        $user = $facebook -> getUser();
        if ($user) {
            try {
                // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
                $user_profile = $facebook -> api('/me');
                //$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me/home');
            } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
                error_log($e);
                $user = null;
            }
        }
        echo $user_profile[name];
        echo $user_profile[id];
        echo $user_profile[picture];
```

I treid them all but nothing is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to echo from the user_profile array.  Try like below $user_profile[name];  its weird with no quotes to string from but that is how we access the arrays.

```
include ('src/facebook.php');    
$app_id = "160336957418730";
$app_secret = "************************";
$facebook = new Facebook( array('appId' => $app_id, 'secret' => $app_secret, ));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    //$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me/home');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
}
        echo $user_profile[name];
        echo $user_profile[id];
        echo $user_profile[picture];
```

Comment: Ive updated my code with this, but still its not working? no output.. any probably reasons?

Comment: have you given you app permission to view your basic info?